# D3 grouped bar chart: How to rotate the text of x axis ticks?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, bar-chart, axis-labels

I'm using the Grouped Bar Chart(http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051), but the text of the x-axis is very long, as shown in attached picture. How to rotate the text? Thank you. [image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A reasonable solution can be found [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html)

The result looks like this:

[image]

Make sure you fully understand this portion of code:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")  
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");
```

`-65` is the angle the label text is rotated, in degrees.

Also, you should increase margin at the bottom, so that the rotated text doesn't get clipped.

WARNING: Rotated text is inevitably rendered by browsers at the end (D3 just creates appropriate svg that is interpreted by browsers), and they do a lousy job rendering rotated text (as opposed to lets say advanced drawing or diagramming software).

Also, related StackOverflow questions:

[rotate-x-axis-text-in-d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252753/rotate-x-axis-text-in-d3)

[how-to-rotate-x-axis-text-in-dimple-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791926/how-to-rotate-x-axis-text-in-dimple-js)

Comment: Can someone clarify those attributes? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to consider using [D3FC](https://d3fc.io/), which has a drop-in replacement for the D3 axis component that supports this feature.

D3FC has an adapter component that will automatically rotate axis labels if they collide:

```
const axis = fc.axisLabelRotate(fc.axisOrdinalBottom(foodScale));
```

Here it is in action:

[image]

**Full disclosure** - I am a maintainer and contributor to the D3FC library!

Comment: any guides on how to make this work when brushing and zooming? Something like`xAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(fc.axisLabelRotate(fc.axisBottom(x)))` doesn't work and I am having difficulty understanding `decorate`.

Answer (score 5):

Use SVG **[transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform)** attribute rotate,

This transform definition specifies a rotation by a degrees about a given point

Try this code :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/PP73D/)**

```
 svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("id", "x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h) + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "rotate(-30)";
    });
```

Comment: Just a note: passing a function into the final `attr()` call isn't required, since the string doesn't depend on the datapoint.