# Whats the best way to auto adjust axis tick increments in D3.js v6 for date fields to avoid overlap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I currently have a simple line chart which displays data and date for y/x axis.

sample data entry:

> [{ "week": "15/11/2020","index": 120}, { "week": "06/11/2020","index":
> 119}]

It works like great up to a certain point when too many data entries are displayed which causes the x-axis labels to overlap each other.

How would I configure tick increments to auto-adjust from using weeks on small data sets and months and year for huge data sets.

**note**: I'm not planning to rotate the labels since it would have the same  overcrowding issue on huge data sets

Before data dump:

[image]

After data dump:

[image]

most of the existing answers in the same nature here are from more than 8 yrs ago, are there any updates on how to fix it in later versions of D3 (v5 - v6)?

here is my d3 code:

```
const xScale = scaleTime()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(
    extent(data, (d: { week: any }) => {
      return d.week;
    })
  );

const yScale = scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([
    min(data, (d: { index: number }) => {
      return d.index;
    }) - 20,
    max(data, (d: { index: number }) => {
      return d.index;
    }) + 20
  ]);

const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale)
   .ticks(data.length);

const svg = select(svgRef.current);

svg
  .select(".x-axis")
  .style("transform", `translateY(${height}px)`)
  .call(xAxis);

const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale);
svg
  .select(".y-axis")
  .call(yAxis);

const myLine = line()
  .x((d: { week: any }) => xScale(d.week))
  .y((d: { index: any }) => yScale(d.index))
  .curve(curveCardinal);

svg
  .selectAll(".line")
  .data([data])
  .join("path")
  .attr("class", "data-circle")
  .attr("d", myLine)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "purple")
  .attr("stroke-width", "5px");

  // draw circle here -- TODO
  svg
  .selectAll(".data-circle")
  .data([data])
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 7.5);
```

Comment: If you want to rotate the labels to prevent the overlap see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947488/d3-grouped-bar-chart-how-to-rotate-the-text-of-x-axis-ticks

Comment: Not really, since it would still be overcrowded if the date range selected would be 6-12 months worth of data or more and data entries are on a weekly basis.

Comment: maybe update your question to say you're not looking for a label rotation solution and what you are open to. E.g. thinning out the labels with larger tick increments e.g. months not weeks etc.