# How to solve the overlapping tick texts on xAxis in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement a line chart which has companies on x-Axis and numbers on Y-axis. The tick values(texts) on x-axis(countries) are overlapping.I have used scalePoint scale for x-axis and scaleLinear for y-axis.

```
const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.style('background-color', 'none');


const width = +svg.attr('width');
const height = +svg.attr('height');

const render = data => {

    const xValue = d => d.FullName;
    const yValue = d => d.TotalCount;

    const margin = { top: 100, right: 70, bottom: 30, left: 100 };
    const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
    const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    const xScale = d3.scalePoint()
        .domain(data.map(xValue))
        .range([0, innerWidth]);

    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, yValue)])
        .range([innerHeight, 0])
        .nice();

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .tickPadding([10])
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
        .tickPadding([10])
        .tickSize(-innerWidth);

    const g = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

    const lineGenerator = d3.line()
        .x(d => xScale(xValue(d)))
        .y(d => yScale(yValue(d)));

    g.append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line-path')
        .attr('d', lineGenerator(data));

    g.selectAll('circle').data(data)
        .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('cx', d => xScale(xValue(d)))
        .attr('cy', d => yScale(yValue(d)))
        .attr('r', 4)
        


    g.append('g').call(yAxis)
        .selectAll('.domain')
        .remove();


    const xAxisG = g.append('g').call(xAxis)
        .attr('transform', `translate(0,${innerHeight})`)


    xAxisG
        .selectAll('.domain,.tick line')
        .remove();
    xAxisG

        g.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'title')
        .attr('y', -20)
        .text('Top 10 Accounts')
}

d3.csv('Q3-Top Accounts.csv').then(data => {
    data.forEach(d => {
        d.TotalCount = +d.TotalCount;
    });
    render(data);
});
```

The x-axis tick values should not be overlapped.The tick texts should have a space between them.Please help me to find a solution for this problem.

The result for the above code looks like this
[image]

Expected Image is below.Please ignore the values.Only need help in arranging the tick text as in the below picture.Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can rotate tick labels 90 degree in x-axis. You can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947488/d3-grouped-bar-chart-how-to-rotate-the-text-of-x-axis-ticks) if you want to rotate labels.

Comment: Thanks for the reply canozsoy. Is there any way to get space between tick texts without rotating them?

Comment: If you move the tick labels' location, wouldn't they show wrong data?