# Change xaxis text orientation on waterfall chart example

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am trying to orientate the x-axis text on the waterfall chart example http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_waterfall

Motivated by [How to rotate x-axis text in dimple.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791926/how-to-rotate-x-axis-text-in-dimple-js) in the console for the above webpage I injected:

```
myChart.axes[0].shapes.selectAll("text").attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");
```

resulting in:

[image]

as can be seen the axis rotate but their position has been translated.

My particular use case can be seen:

[image]

there are more categories and the axis text needs to be rotated to prevent overflow.
How would I rotate the axis text (in my case I want -90 degrees rather then -45) and prevent the resulting position translation?

In the case of the dimplejs website example I can do

```
myChart.axes[0].shapes.selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-150, 200) rotate(-90)")
```

to manually align the text:

[image]

On my particular chart with more categories I need to do:

```
myChart.axes[0].shapes.selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-130, 140) rotate(-90)")
```

A nasty hack with coordinates that need to be manually changed depending on data.

Comment: Have you tried rotating about the center of the `text` element instead of the coordinate origin?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have tried rotating then translating with respect to the parents boundary box `this.parentNode.getBBox()` this seems to get pretty close for my use case (-90 rotation).

Comment: Well it seems to me what you really want in this case is change the rotation point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is specific to the way that I've done the waterfall chart example.  Dimple has built in rotation for long labels as you can see in [this example](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_responsive_sizing) when you resize the popup.

Unfortunately in order to deal with duplicate x values I created the x dimension in the waterfall example which takes an integer that then gets replaced with the text label after drawing.  This means that the sizing logic thinks there is just a single digit integer and doesn't do the rotation.  Here's the code from the dimple source for rotating x values:

```
axis.shapes.selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .each(function () {
         var rec = this.getBBox();
         d3.select(this)
            .attr("transform", "rotate(90," + (rec.x + rec.width) + "," + (rec.y + (rec.height / 2)) + ") translate(5, 0)");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @John Kiernander that works perfectly. Great library quite intuitive.